# how this example comes UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python

When I try to learn more about python, I found this page:http://python.jobbole.com/88045/ . Ok,I must say it was wrote by Chinese.

Here is a example:

```
import random

def func(ok):
    if ok:
        a = random.random()
    else:
        import random
        a = random.randint(1, 10)
    return a

func(True)# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'random' referenced before assignment
```

The words, `referenced before assignment`, I could not understand, in my thought, I had import the random at the top.

Through I import random the second time in `else`, but I had import random before use,is yet?

So, anyone can help me about the `UnboundLocalError` when I import more than once?

I am new to python, and my English is not good enough, so please point out what I had not explain enough or the words that not polite enough.

Thanks!

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Comment: If you take out the second `import random`, do you get better behavior? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: codes `a = random.random`.

in the tool ,pycharm,the first `a = random.random`,first `random` was Drawed red line.

And when I run the .py file, the error comes from it also.

Comment: I know if I not use the second import random, the error would not come. But I  want to konw why when I use the second import , the error comes?In my thought, it is OK.